# Angular momentum completeness relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, normalization, spherical-harmonics

Can anyone tell me if the angular momentum completeness relation is given by
$$
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^{l} (2l + 1) |l,m\rangle\langle l,m| = I
$$
or

$$
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^{l} |l,m\rangle\langle l,m| = I
$$
Because I remember the first one but I see a lot of places use the second one. Can someone tell me what happens to the normalization factor? Also, the first one is similar to the Peter-Weyl theorem so it seems more legitmate.

Comment: Depends entirely on how you choose the normalize the states $| l , m \rangle$.

Comment: Ok. So both are correct?

Comment: Hint: operate with either on $|l' m'\rangle$. Derive the normalization  for each.

Comment: @Dr.user44690 - again, it depends on your choice of normalization. Depending on that, one of the two is correct. Both cannot simultaneously be correct.